# Trying to find gaps between dates in PHP

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to find gaps between dates, example:

```
$arrayTest = (
              array('from'=>'2017-07-10 15:22:45', 'to'=>'2017-07-11 16:22:46'),
              array('from'=>'2017-07-11 16:22:47', 'to'=>'2017-08-05 07:10:09'),
              array('from'=>'2017-08-05 07:10:10', 'to'=>'2017-09-22 09:25:12'),
              array('from'=>'2017-09-22 09:25:15', 'to'=>'2017-10-18 08:13:58'),
              array('from'=>'2017-10-18 08:13:58', 'to'=>'2017-11-29 13:29:12')
);
```

In this example, the line 4 *from* (2017-09-22 09:25:15) has 3 seconds more than line 3 *to* (2017-09-22 09:25:12). I guess the best way to do this is converting to timestamp *strtotime()*, but I'm a bit confused: how would be the best way to check that groups of From->To.. if somehow there's a gap in between?

Output: For this case, just return 1 (or the number of gaps), cause there's one gap.
if all periods connect and is not missing any *"space"*, returns 0.

Comment: can yo show how's your desired output look like?

Comment: @AlivetoDie For this case, just return 1 (or the number of gaps), cause there's one gap. If all periods connect and is not missing any _"space"_, returns 0.

Comment: isnt there a one second gap between lines 1 and 2? and 2 and 3? so it would return 3?

Comment: @logo din't get you. can yo show what type of array  you want as an excepted answer?

Comment: yeah, the question is either unclear or simply counting how many differences between "from" and the previous to that is > 0

Comment: I think @Andreas got the idea

Comment: @JapanGuy depends if the glass is half full or half empty. One could say that 1-2 and 2-3 is "normal" and 4-5 is an overlap.

Comment: @Andreas fair enough. OP could've mentioned that in the question

Comment: Are these time spans in order? Or you want to be able to detect the time difference between time spans even if they are shuffled?

Comment: @JapanGuy absolutely! I just noted what he asked for and made it happen. Didn't think to much about what is "correct or not".

Comment: @JapanGuy Andreas, I kinda explained, mentioning the example *the line 4 from (2017-09-22 09:25:15) has 3 seconds more than line 3 to (2017-09-22 09:25:12)*, so I thought that this was implying the result expected. When I was trying to be more specific Andreas posted the example. Anyway, thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop and use strtotime.

```
$arr = array(
          array('from'=>'2017-07-10 15:22:45', 'to'=>'2017-07-11 16:22:46'),
          array('from'=>'2017-07-11 16:22:47', 'to'=>'2017-08-05 07:10:09'),
          array('from'=>'2017-08-05 07:10:10', 'to'=>'2017-09-22 09:25:12'),
          array('from'=>'2017-09-22 09:25:15', 'to'=>'2017-10-18 08:13:58'),
          array('from'=>'2017-10-18 08:13:58', 'to'=>'2017-11-29 13:29:12')
);
$gap = false;
For($i=0; $i<count($arr)-1; $i++){ //I count to -1 due to $i+1 in the calculation below
    $diff = strtotime ($arr[$i+1]['from']) - strtotime ($arr[$i]['to']);
    If($diff >1){ // if there is more than one second gap
        $gap = true;
        Echo "key " . $i . " to " . ($i+1) .". Missing " .$diff . " seconds";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/pNviX